# "Happy to" vs "happy for"

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, idioms, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

What should I say to wish someone a happy Easter ??

1- Happy Easter to you and your beloved ones.

2 - Happy Easter for you and your beloved ones.

Comment: Happy Easter to... is the correct usage for wishing.

Answer (score 1):

If you were in a normal converstion, you would most likely just say "Happy Easter." "Happy Easter to you" is better than "Happy Easter for you;" I don't think I've ever head someone say "Happy Easter for you." "Happy Easter to you" doesn't sound as natural as "Happy Easter," but "Happy Easter to you and your loved ones" sounds more natural, except is quite formal, and it would not normally be said in conversation. But if you're looking to be formal, then feel free to use it!
Hopefully this helps,
Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the useful info. I will stick to "happy easter"

Answer (score 1):

"Happy  to you."

The phrase is a way of offering a type of blessing from yourself *to* a person.

*For* would be used to discuss how Easter functioned for the other person. For example:
*I hope Easter will be happy for you.*

In this case, you'd be describing how you wish Easter will function for the person.

Comment: Totally agree , thanks for the explanation